# How to start Workflow automatically when due date arrives or passed

Tags: sharepoint-designer

need some help with workflows. need to send email to users when due date arrives and passed. I have created the workflow and it works manually but automatically also tried retention stage

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two general strategies for this. The first is to start the workflow when the item is added and add a wait task to wait until the specified date.

The other strategy is to use retention to start the workflow. You mentioned that you tried this. Did something about it not work for you? Retention is a [bit trick](https://mikesnotebook.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/sharepoint-retention-policies/)y to set up and test. One factor is that the timer jobs run over the weekend by default, so if you set it up this week and think that it hasn't worked, you may just need to wait until monday. (or, if you have farm admin rights, you can also kick off the timer jobs manually).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a site workflow to run daily verify the get the list items based on the REST query and verify the conditions and sent emails.

Here is a sample which you can apply for workflow

[image]

This workflow runs daily once.